# Executing multiple processes of c++ program

Tags: c++, linux, fork

I have a C++ program. I am executing it on LInux. I want to execute this multiple instances of this program with different arguments. Eg:

./exeutableProgram  file.txt
./exeutableProgram  file2.txt
./exeutableProgram  file3.txt

In other words, I want to create multiple processes such that each process run on different processor.

How can I achieve this task?
Do I need to make some program using fork()? or I need to write some shell script? 
Please provide some guidance in this regard.

Comment: @Mayerz yes shell script

Comment: each process run on different processor? not necessarily. You might just have one single processor, but the Kernel can do the time slicing for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a bash script to do this:

```
for var in "$@" <-- loops over all of the arguments and sets them to var.
do
    /path/to/executableProgram $var & <-- executes the program with current var 
                                          as argument, & means background process.
done
```

The `&` will background the process and they should be allocated to different cores by your operating system.

You could then call with:

```
./Script file*.txt  <-- '*' is the wildcard character meaning all files with 
                         the signature file??.txt (file1.txt, file2.txt etc) will
                         all become arguments.
```

Comment: Is there any difference between achieving this task with the help of script and using Linux fork()?

Comment: `fork()` means writting a program which opens the same executable lots of times, It is the same as what i have done here except it will be much more difficult. `fork()` is more typiclly used for things like client server applications where the server forks to handle each client.

Comment: I have not written much scripts. Can you please explain me what $var & is doing. When I call this script can I issue more than one argument?

Comment: @Zara I have edited the answer to provide more detail.

Comment: Thanks. By different arguments I meant ./Script file*.txt  LogFile*.txt. In other words the executable needs two files as arguments. One file is on which it does processing and on other file it writes the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the `util-linux` package on your Linux distribution, you can use the [`taskset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) command to start your process on a specific CPU. To start your program on core 0 and then core 5:

```
$ taskset 0x1 ./executableProgram file.txt
$ taskset 0x20 ./executableProgram file2.txt
```